# Find filter definition

Tags: magento2, filter

I am looking to the file `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer` (a preference actually but that's not the point).

This class defines `public function render(FilterInterface $filter)`

I'm looking to understand where and how the `$filter` is initialized.

If I'm looking to `$filter->getItems()` I have a list of items filtered, my objective is to alterate one the these items so I look where for exemple the filter with name filterA is defined.